# String variable inside src tag causing rendering issues

Tags: pug

I have a pug template that looks like this:

```
extends base

block body 
  p #{data.script}
  script(src="#{data.script}" type="text/javascript")
```

If I remove the last line containing the script tag, my template renders. However, the quoting around the `#{data.script}` is not being interpreted correctly. How can I use a pug variable inside an `src` tag?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Pug removed support for interpolation in attribute values. If you are using a recent version of node.js you can just use template strings. This works:

```
extends base

block body 
  p #{data.script}
  script(src=`${data.script}` type="text/javascript")
```

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2302